# Use Google Feeling Lucky as search engine

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os, google-search

I use Google search engine a lot and I usually select the first result of Google search. How can I force Chrome to automatically select the best result without showing the search result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set "Google Feeling Lucky" as default engine:

1) Chrome Settings -> Search -> Manage Search Engines

[image]

2) add new search engine with a deliberate name and keyword.

3) In the third box for the URL, paste `http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=%s`

4) Click on make this my default.

[image]

Now if you search any phrase, it will redirect to the best result without showing the google search result.

Even if you mistype in your search, google automatically redirect you to the best result neglecting your typo. for example searching `stakoverflow` will direct you to correct result.

This solution can be extended to other browsers as well.

Answer (score 2):

As of Jul 2017, follow the steps provided by Woeitg and use this URL as your search engine:
`https://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=%s`

[image: Chrome settings]

Comment: This is the correct answer, I would replace the `http` schema with `https` to keep the communication secured.

Comment: This doesn't work right now https://superuser.com/questions/1496083/google-feeling-lucky-url-causing-redirect-notice