# Google "Feeling Lucky" url causing redirect notice

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

I've noticed the feeling lucky url (with `btnI` query parameter) is now resulting in a redirect notice page. What's the deal?

[image]

Comment: @Drazen Bjelovuk When I go to google.com, enter _Tony Packo's_ and click on I'm Feeling Lucky, I get to where I should: https://www.tonypacko.com/ Please clar your cache and cookies and retry.

Comment: This is about constructing the redirect url outside of that context (e.g. a custom search engine string).

Comment: No solution but there's a thread about this https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/15794018?hl=en

Comment: @SanghyunLee gave forum link about issue & someone mentioned maybe google broke this on purpose as it subverts their ad's which is their money so I'm guessing they won't fix it. Duckduckgo has similar functionality I guess: `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!ducky+ham` per this blog post: https://travishorn.com/link-directly-to-googles-i-m-feeling-lucky-feature-65ebe7b552bd

Comment: I think probably people were using google.com redirects to add some credibility to malicious links. — Anyway, this userscript solves it for me: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/390770-workaround-for-google-i-m-feeling-lucky-redirect. Duckduckgo is an other alternative.

Answer (score 17):

Using this search string works for me:

https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&btnI=&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1

Where %s is the placeholder for the actual search term.
Not sure what the meaning of sourceid and gfns is though.

Taken from here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/2y3vvt/im_feeling_lucky_or_auto_redirecting_in_url/cpkbbaw?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Any idea where these query parameters might be documented?  I don't see them anywhere online and it feels a little too close to magic to be a long-term fix.  The Reddit post just pasted an example without context.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like they've introduced a csrf-like mechanism in the form of a query parameter (`iflsig`). I've tried copying the one generated from a traditional "Feeling Lucky" request into my search url:

`http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aen.wikipedia.org+{keyword}&btnI&iflsig=AAP1E1EAAAAAXbODt-rzChgYf5wDoUWplGXrcvsZ0qOk`

Which does work temporarily, but this token is ephemeral and invalidates after a few minutes, so it's not a real solution.

Not sure if anyone from Google has commented on this, but I'll circle back if I hear of any developments.

**Update:** My workaround is to just use DuckDuckGo instead.

E.g. for first result from Wikipedia:

`https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%5Csite%3Aen.wikipedia.org+<search_term>`

`%5C` (url-encoded backslash) is the redirect identifier here.

Comment: on DuckDuckGo, you can use the bang `!ducky` to forward to the first result

Comment: I tried using the duckduckgo url, but found it only worked if I unescaped the `%5C` to ``\`` and `3A` to `:` when using it in the search address bar

Comment: DuckDuckGo just works  - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Use this Userscript: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/390770-workaround-for-google-i-m-feeling-lucky-redirect/code

> **Workaround for Google I'm Feeling Lucky Redirect**
>
> Immediately redirects when google prompts 'redirection notice'. Used to circumvent google pestering you when querying with I'm Feeling Lucky feature.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you see the redirect notice.

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> will select the link Google's feeling lucky would normally redirect to
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> will navigate you to the link you just selected using <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install the extension [Skip Redirect](https://github.com/sblask/webextension-skip-redirect). It's available for Chrome and Firefox.

It will skip the redirect page entirely so this is faster than using userscripts like [Google I'm Feeling Lucky Redirect](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/422086-google-i-m-feeling-lucky-redirect)
 and [Workaround for Google I'm Feeling Lucky Redirect](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/390770-workaround-for-google-i-m-feeling-lucky-redirect/code).

Note that Skip Redirect is very aggressive in skipping URLs and might cause problem in other websites, so you might want to limit redirection to `https://www.google.com/url?q=*` only in the settings:

[image: setting screenshot 1]

[image: setting screenshot 2]